# Cumulative function of linear transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, linear-transformations

Let's assume that we have a vector of RVs: $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \dots, X_n)^{\top}$ — and its linear transformation $\mathbf{Y} = A \mathbf{X}$. As usual, let's assume $A$ is $n\times n$, not degenerate — just in case.

For continuous random variables, we have a nice and neat formula with Jacobian, but we take the existence of the pdf for granted; but what happens in case of discrete variables, Poisson, for example? Are there any known closed-form formulas explaining relations of $\mathbf{X}$'s and $\mathbf{Y}$'s CDFs?

Comment: For exactly what do we have a formula?

Comment: For pdfs, see [this one](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Random_Variables_and_Probability_Density_Functions#Probability_Densities_of_Linear_Transformations_of_RVs) or [this file, page 6](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic133498.files/5-mrv_func.pdf) @zoli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ has an inverse and if $Y=A X$ then $X=A^{-1}Y$. So for a (measurable) set $B$ in $R^n$
$$Q_Y(B)=P(Y\in B)=P(X\in A^{-1}B)=Q_X(A^{-1}B).$$

So, the relationship between the distributions is simple. If the pdf's exist then **the** special formula can be derived based on the dollowing integral:

$$Q_Y(B)=\iint\cdots \int_Bf_Y(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)dy_1dy_2\cdots dy_n=...$$

Comment: Oddly enough, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!